# Apache & mod_rewrite - index not found

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This works as desired, except that `index` or anything in an 'index directory' such as `index/foo` will fail.

```
RewriteEngine on

# base dir
RewriteBase /project/

# allow assets/ directory
RewriteRule ^(assets)/(.*)$ $0 [L]

# direct all else to index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

I've attempted this, but it still does not catch it:

```
RewriteRule ^index(/.*)?$ index.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
# base dir
RewriteBase /project/

# allow assets/ directory
RewriteRule ^(assets)/(.*)$ $0 [L]

# direct all else to index.php
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php$).*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.